# You are using an outdated version of Java (11). Java 17 or higher is required

Tags: java, error-handling

I got this error message but I have no idea how to get rid of it. I installed Java 18 and created a variable so I am out of ideas.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rocSB.png)
[Did I do the variable correctly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt9cW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try to go to control panel/Apps and look for java 11 software then uninstall?

Comment: Have you also check the version just to check if jdk is working? Ahm.. there is no need for command you can just type in search bar  then type control panel

Comment: Based on my understanding you have already java 11 but your project required java 17+, that why you change it to java18. If you type in CMD javac --version and will show no error that means java 11 is still running to your software. And maybe the way you install java 11 is by software , thats why i let you uninstall it , by going to app if not there you can look to control panel then click uninstall program

Comment: command prompt says i am in java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22

Comment: Here reference even you delete the folder of java 11 then change the path to other version and the prevoius software exist its still running https://www.java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.html then restart after uninstall

Answer (score 0):

You also have to change your PATH variable. As You can see in the image the PATH Points to jdk11.

JAVA_HOME has to be set for the tooling chain (maven, gradle, a.s.o.). You should change your PATH to meet: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. (Sorry I used Windows long time ago and don't remember exactly how to dereference environment variables).

This whole thing works like this: The PATH variable is used by your OS to tell where executables can be found. When you type a command in terminal, all this locations are searched. First come, first server. So if you have two JDK,s defined in your path, the first one wins. So you can avoid this by defining the PATH entry by dereferencing JAVA_HOME.

To test in your terminal which java is used type `java --version`. Changes of environment variables are only valid for terminals opened after the change. Old terminals hold the old values. If You are not sure do a reboot after changing the variable.

Have a look at https://www.codejava.net/java-core/how-to-set-java-home-environment-variable-on-windows-10 . There you have a good explanation what happens.

Comment: like this?
https://imgur.com/a/5yo1YDO

Comment: I think that path java to bin is should be in "System variable not in User variable" while java_home is correct is in User variable

Comment: Yes exactly like this. But as I've seen you have C;\...\Oracle\java\javapath in your system variable path. I know this is done when the oracle installer was used. I really don't like this stuff. If You are Admin you could remove this entry from system variables, reboot and It should be solved. To know what is going on read http://makble.com/jdk-8-and-cprogramdataoraclejavajavapath . (I really recommand to delete the entry cause in my opinion, it is not the way OSes do path handling.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help, 2 step to configure jdk to machine in User Variable and System Variable. And remove the previous software of jdk in the machine.

[image: User variable "JAVA_HOME"and System Variable "Path"][image: Uninstall the JAVA 11 software]